# Função escrevendo valores mais de uma vez - PyQT5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt-5

Olá

Estou usando usando o pyqt5 para criar a interface gráfica de uma suposta loja de roupas (estou treinando), tenho os campos para receber os dados para cadastro de cada tipo de roupa, porém ao clicar no botão cadastrar ele salva no arquivo txt os dados corretos, porém ao cadastrar uma segunda peça ele cadastra duas vezes a mesma coisa, se cadastrar uma terceira peça ele cadastra 4 e assim por diante, alguém sabe o que pode ser? Código abaixo.

```
from PyQt5 import uic,QtWidgets


def CadastrarProdutos():
    cadastrar.show()
    description = cadastrar.lineEdit.text()
    price = cadastrar.lineEdit_2.text()
    amount = cadastrar.lineEdit_3.text()
    dados = description, price, amount
    cadastrar.pushButton.clicked.connect(SalvarDados_cadastro)
    return dados

def SalvarDados_cadastro():
    dados_save = CadastrarProdutos()
    print(dados_save)
    db = open("Estoque.txt","a+")
    dados_formatados = ("|".join(dados_save)) + "\n"
    db.write(dados_formatados)
    db.close()
    
try:
   with open('Estoque.txt', 'r') as f:
       pass
except IOError:
    create_db = open("Estoque.txt","a+")
    create_db.write("Descricao|Preco|Quantidade\n")
    create_db.close()
    
app=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
menu=uic.loadUi("menu_button.ui")
menu.pushButton.clicked.connect(CadastrarProdutos)
cadastrar=uic.loadUi("cadastro_button.ui")

menu.show()
app.exec()
```

Os dados são salvos da forma demonstrada abaixo após eu tentar cadastrar os seguintes itens: Camiseta, camiseta rosa e camiseta rosa curta com seus respectivos valores e quantidades.

```
('Camiseta', '15', '10')
('Camiseta Rosa', '16', '4')
('Camiseta Rosa', '16', '4')
('Camiseta Rosa curta', '14', '26')
('Camiseta Rosa curta', '14', '26')
('Camiseta Rosa curta', '14', '26')
('Camiseta Rosa curta', '14', '26')
```

Eu preciso armazenar somente 1 de cada vez, alguém sabe me dizer aonde estou errando? Obrigado.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler  [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 1):

Olá, não consegui correr o teu código, mas tens aqui um exemplo que faz o que precisas:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class TelaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TelaPrincipal, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tela Principal')
        self.setGeometry(100, 200, 300, 200)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        self.description = QLineEdit()
        self.price = QLineEdit()
        self.amount = QLineEdit()

        self.cadastrar = QPushButton('Salvar Dados')
        self.cadastrar.clicked.connect(self.salvar_dados_cadastro)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.description)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.price)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.amount)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cadastrar)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.check_txt_file()

    def check_txt_file(self):
        exist = os.path.exists('Estoque.txt')
        if exist is False:
            create_db = open("Estoque.txt", "a+")
            create_db.write("Descricao|Preco|Quantidade\n")
            create_db.close()

    def cadastrar_produtos(self):
        dados = f'{self.description.text()}, {self.price.text()},
                  {self.amount.text()}\n'
        return dados

    def salvar_dados_cadastro(self):
        dados = self.cadastrar_produtos()

        with open('Estoque.txt', 'a+') as w:
            w.write(dados)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = TelaPrincipal()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```